# SDWebImage does not follow 307 redirects

Tags: ios, objective-c, redirect, uiimage, sdwebimage

I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to fetch images in my project, but I'm facing just one issue that I haven't been able to solve so far.

Basically if an image has a temporary redirect (**307 redirect** which nowadays is a standard code for redirect) the library doesn't follow the redirect and just returns an error.

This doesn't happen with images with a **302 redirect**. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

PS: Just in case someone needs the code on how I'm loading the images, I'm doing this:

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:imageURL
                 options:0
                progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                     // progression tracking code
                }
               completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
                if (image) {
                    [_photo setImage:image];
                }
            }];
```

Comment: I think you should open an issue on GitHub...Maybe the author could say something on the argument.

Comment: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/search?q=redirect&type=Issues